# How to build a Morphia query on a subset of the properties of a Java Collection's elements?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

I'm not being able to query a MongoDB document according to field values of an embedded Java Collection.

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class StationHistoryEntry // extends ...
{
    @Embedded
    private Set<SongFeedback> songFeedback = new HashSet<SongFeedback>();

    // ...
}
```

And the following embedded class:

```
@Embedded
public class SongFeedback // extends ...
{
    @Embedded
    private FeedbackType feedbackType;

    private ObjectId userId;

    public enum FeedbackType {
        THUMBS_UP, THUMBS_DOWN, STAR;
    }

    // other properties
}
```

What I need to do is to find `StationHistoryEntries` that have `SongFeedback` with a given `userId` and `feedbackType=STAR`.

I've tried the following but didn't succeed when the other `SongFeedback` properties (the ones not shown on the code snippet because I don't have control over their values) were not `null`, which happens in production:

```
public List<StationHistoryEntry> findStarredByUserId(ObjectId userId) {
    SongFeedback songFeedback = new SongFeedback(FeedbackType.STAR, userId);
    return ds.find(StationHistoryEntry.class)
        .filter("songFeedback elem", songFeedback).asList();
}
```

And I've also tried the following, but it always returns an empty list:

```
public List<StationHistoryEntry> findStarredByUserId(ObjectId userId) {
    Query<StationHistoryEntry> query = ds.createQuery(StationHistoryEntry.class);
    query.and(
        query.criteria("songFeedback.userId").equal(userId),
        query.criteria("songFeedback.feedbackType").equal(FeedbackType.STAR));
    return query.asList();
}
```

If it helps at all, I've created a Github repository with the stripped down code and a unit test: https://github.com/gabrielcs/MorphiaQueryStackOverflow

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public List<StationHistoryEntry> findStarredByUserId(ObjectId userId) {
    Query<StationHistoryEntry> query = ds.createQuery(StationHistoryEntry.class);
    query.and(
        query.criteria("songFeedback.userId").equal(userId),
        query.criteria("songFeedback.feedbackType").in(FeedbackType.STAR));
    return query.asList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I've got a compilation error because `in()` expects an `Iterable`. If it helps at all, I've created a Github repository with the stripped down code and a unit test: https://github.com/gabrielcs/MorphiaQueryStackOverflow

Comment: you can wrap it in a List:  Arrays.asList(FeedbackType.STAR)

Comment: No more compilation error. However, what happens is if I'm querying for starred songs by `userId1` and have a `StationHistoryEntry s` with a `THUMBS_UP SongFeedback` by `userId1` and a `STAR SongFeedback` by `userId2`, than the result will contain `s`, which shouldn't happen. What I need in the query result for `findStarredByUserId(userId1)` is only `StationHistoryEntries` that have at least 1 single SongFeedback with both `userId1` and `STAR`.